# How do I get a ColorRamp field into an addon menu?

Tags: python, texturing, node-editor, interface, add-on

I'm back again with a code problem that's probably obvious to everyone else.
I'm trying to make a one-stop menu for the initial setup of a texture system I've developed, and I'm having trouble getting things to show up on the menu. I'm using a UI code template from another post here, I forget which one, but the author is listed as 'p2or'.

I managed to make a property that my first script can read and use, now I need a way to control other aspects from the menu I'm making.
Ideally I'd like to have all the colours and important options available in the menu.

> but for now I'm just trying to figure out how to get the Texture >Coordinate Object Property menu To show up as a menu item.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Menus
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_MT_CustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Character Object"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # Built-in operators
        layout.operator("object.select", bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["Texture Coordinate"].object)
 #       layout.operator("object.select_all", text="Select/Deselect All").action = 'TOGGLE'
 #       layout.operator("object.select_all", text="Inverse").action = 'INVERT'
 #       layout.operator("object.select_random", text="Random")
```

> Hasn't worked, and I know it has to be something I'm not calling, but
> I have no idea what.

Gorgious helped me with the object selection one, turns out I needed to call it as layout.prop

Since that works, I'm now curious what other pieces of syntax I'm not aware of.

I would also like to make a button to execute the image generation script, if anyone has advice on that.

```
class WM_OT_HelloWorld(Operator):
    bl_label = "Populate Masks"
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world"

    def execute(self, context):
#        scene = context.scene
#        mytool = scene.my_tool
#        filename = "//imggen.py"
        exec(bpy.data.texts["imggen"].name)

        # print the values to the console
#        print("Hello World")
#        print("bool state:", mytool.my_bool)
#        print("int value:", mytool.my_int)
#        print("float value:", mytool.my_float)
#        print("string value:", mytool.my_string)
#        print("enum state:", mytool.my_enum)

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I've tried calling it as a file, and from within Blender, same result.
Currently the button just tells me:

> line 105, in execute
> File "", line 1, in 
> NameError: name 'imggen' is not defined

**Update:**
So I managed to get the color function linked to the node map and visible in the menu I'm making.

```
my_float_vector: FloatVectorProperty(
        name = "Interior 1",
        subtype = "COLOR",
        size = 4,
        description="Should be Red or Pink",
        default=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 
        min= 0.0, # float
        max = 1.0
        ) 

mat = bpy.data.materials['Skin']
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
node = nodes.get("RGB.005")
# change the color
node.outputs[0].default_value = (bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].my_tool.my_float_vector)
```

This presents a new minor problem, where when I change the color in the new menu, it doesn't update in the node map unless I run the script again. I'm thinking of making an **Update Button** for the colors, but if anyone knows a way to get it to update live, that would be better.

Still haven't managed to get the other button to run the image generator script.

**Update**

So I got back to it today and tried to run the script so I could try the update solution posted earlier, and now I'm getting this:

```
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'my_tool'
```

It's choking on this:

```
node.outputs[0].default_value = (bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].my_tool.my_float_vector)
```

If I comment it out then run the script it works, then I can uncomment it, run it again and then it takes.
Some quick searching indicates I need to register 'my_tool' at some point, but when I try, it chokes on that, so clearly I'm not doing it right.

I also tried the update function in the float vector group, and it also chokes on that.

```
line 70, in MyProperties
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

```
my_float_vector: FloatVectorProperty(
        name = "Interior 1",
        subtype = "COLOR",
        size = 4,
        description="Should be Red or Pink",
        default=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 
        min= 0.0, # float
        max = 1.0,
        update = (self,context)
        )
```

I've tried it as different lines in that group, same result.

**Update**

As I've been experimenting with functions, I've decided that several of my functions would be best served by placing the colorramp interfaces right in the addon menu.

I found this little snippet:

```
cr_node = bpy.data.node_groups["NodeGroup.002"].nodes["ColorRamp"].name
layout.template_color_ramp(cr_node, "color_ramp", expand=True)
```

But I don't know what class of zone it needs, and I can't find a list of them anywhere. If there is one on the Blender API I'd appreciate a link.
It gave me this error:

```
NameError: name 'layout' is not defined
```

**Update**

I fixed that, more or less, it was in the wrong place. Now it's giving me this:

```
TypeError: UILayout.template_color_ramp(): error with argument 1, "data" -  Function.data expected a AnyType type, not str
```

Comment: `layout.prop(bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["Texture Coordinate"], "object")` ?

Comment: I see! `layout.prop` That makes sense! 
Ok, now to see if I can recreate that success with other properties.
Now, are there other types of property for that context I should be aware of?

Comment: It depends on what you want the user to be able to tweak. You can display pretty much any property that's displayed on the node

Comment: re your update : you should look into prop definition `update` callback https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty that lets you run code when you change a property value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally found the answer to this, [in another post.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19289/are-ui-color-ramps-possible-through-python)

I had found this before, but it didn't work for me, and I finally figured out why.

```
cr_node = bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['ColorRamp']
layout.template_color_ramp(cr_node, "color_ramp", expand=True)
```

This works if the node in on the base layer, but my system has a lot of frames and groups, which I didn't realize before was an important distinction.
My final code for this function looks more like this:

```
cr_node = bpy.data.node_groups["NodeGroup.002"].nodes["ColorRamp"]
layout.template_color_ramp(cr_node, "color_ramp", expand=True)
```

The only problem with this is I can't put a label on it the same way I did the RGB fields.